# Magento 1.9 touch screen problem on windows 8 (chrome & firefox)

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, rwd, windows, chrome-browser

I have a Magento 1.9 installation and I have problem with menu of new responsive theme of Magento.
The problem is with a windows 8 laptop with touch screen display and only with Chrome & Firefox. IE does not have any problem. 
By mouse over on Menu the drop down does not work. 
I have disabled the touch screen option on Chrome by using chrome://flags. That will solve the problem. 
Does have anyone have a solution for this problem without disabling the browser touch screen option. 
I should also mention it is not possible to scroll the screen with the browser bar.

Comment: I too have the same problem the Menu doesn't work when there is a drop down in IE and IPad

Comment: This is a bug reported here:
[Issue #5398](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/37)

It seems to be closed however latest release still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, modify app.js in your skin folder and at line 153:

Change

`var pointerEvent = 'touchend';`

to

`var pointerEvent = 'mouseover';`

There is also a bug with the zoom on the product view (zoom isn't active on the first image), change line 711 from:

`ProductMediaManager.createZoom($j(".no-touch .gallery-image.visible")); //set zoom on first image`

to:

`ProductMediaManager.createZoom($j(".gallery-image.visible")); //set zoom on first image`

Of course, if you modifiy app.js, it will be overwritten in the next version and you should not do it, but hopefuly these bugs will be resolved in the next version ;)

Thanks to Alfred Stephenson => http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/308

**EDIT:**

The version on demo.magentocommerce.com is working correctly. The difference is in app.js, on line 189:

```
}).on('click', function (event) {
    var elem = $j(this);
    if (elem.data('has-touch')) {
        elem.data('has-touch', false);
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    if(Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:" + bp.medium + "px)")) {
        var elem = $j(this).parent();

        var alreadyExpanded = elem.hasClass('menu-active');

        nav.find('li.level0').removeClass('menu-active');

        // Collapse all active sub-menus
        nav.find('.sub-menu-active').removeClass('sub-menu-active');

        if (!alreadyExpanded) {
            elem.addClass('menu-active');
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

change it to:

```
}).on('click', function (event) {
    var elem = $j(this);
    if (elem.data('has-touch')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    elem.data('has-touch', false);
```